# Returning values from functions

Tags: python, function, helper

Trying to create a program that determines discounts in a book shop, unsure about returning values from functions to main though, Help would be greatly appreciated

```
def main():
print (" Please enter the amount spent on the following items:")
Books = int(input("Books: "))
Magazines= int(input("Magazines: "))
Newspapers= int(input("Newspapers: "))
print (book_disc)

def discounts(Books, Magazines, Newspapers):
       book_disc = Books - (Books *.2)
       mag_disc = Magazines - (Magazines*.1)
       news_disc =  Newspapers
return discounts
return (book_disc, mag_disc, news_disc)




main()
```

Comment: Is your indentation off (for your return statements)

Comment: For return I have it lined up with the function it's inside i.e. return lines up with def

Comment: @user3241651: That doesn't work in Python. Indentation is significant. You must indent your `return` along with the rest of the function body. Your code as posted is not valid Python.

Comment: That would be why. Indentation is important in python, it needs to be aligned inside the function. Indent it to match the rest and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found:

You had some indentation issues

You are trying `print (book_disc)` before `book_disc` is defined (it's now been removed)

Your `return`s were out of order `return (book_disc, mag_disc, news_disc)` needed to be in your `discounts()` function

`return discounts` needed arguments

```
def main():
    print (" Please enter the amount spent on the following items:")
    Books = int(input("Books: "))
    Magazines= int(input("Magazines: "))
    Newspapers= int(input("Newspapers: "))
    def discounts(Books, Magazines, Newspapers):
           book_disc = Books - (Books *.2)
           mag_disc = Magazines - (Magazines*.1)
           news_disc =  Newspapers
           return (book_disc, mag_disc, news_disc)
    return discounts(Books, Magazines, Newspapers)

main()
```